# Create your own texuture from image

Tags: texturing, image

I have a large image that I want to turn into a texture, with roughness and a normal map.

I've never done this before and am wondering what methods are available and if there's a preferred approach?

I would be very grateful for tips!

Comment: You have some softwares that do that, also some websites, but the result will also depend on your texture, for example if the lighting and shadows are not correct it won't work fine, how does your texture look like?

Comment: What software would you recommend? I can share you the texture if you message me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert an image to a normal map, but the result will depend on the lighting you have, if its low angle it won't be interpreted correctly of course as dark is supposed to be hollows and white is supposed to be heights...

You can do it with [Photopea](https://www.photopea.com/) for example (it's an online version of Photoshop), open the image and *Filter > 3D > Normal Map* (put a bit of *Blur*), then *File > Export As > PNG*.

You can also do it with Krita, [Normalmap Online](https://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/), etc...

As for the *Roughness*, if black parts are supposed to be rough and white glossy, just plug the image texture into the *Roughness* input of the *Principled BSDF*, the values of the image will be interpreted as 0 to 1 values. You could also blur a bit the image in an image editor if you want to avoid too sharp edges.

Comment: Thank you so much!